# Custom shipping - Free with upgrade option

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We offer 2 type of delivery to uk customers

spend over £100 and get it free special delivery

spend under £100 and get it free 1st class record but option of Special Delivery for extra £3.

Cannot work out how to enable to in Magento (1.7.0.2)

So how can I add the free with £3 option for carts less than £100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this extension: http://www.webshopapps.com/uk/free/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

This is the table I used:

> "Country","Region/State","City","Zip/Postal Code From","Zip/Postal Code To","Order Subtotal From","Order Subtotal To","Shipping Price","Delivery Type"
>   "GBR","*","*","*","*","0","99.99","0","Free 1st Class Recorded"
>   "GBR","*","*","*","*","0","99.99","3","Upgrade to Special Delivery Next Day before 1pm"
>   "GBR","*","*","*","*","100","9999","0","Free Special Delivery Next Day before 1pm"

Which works like a charm - hope this helps

Comment: Caveat to this is that if you then add optional extras to the product, the extebsion doesnt calculate the price on the cart, on the net amount of the primary product - the paid version used the cart total including chargeable options